# Redirection using Scrapy Spider Middleware (Unhandled error in Deferred)

Tags: redirect, captcha, middleware, scrapy

I've made a spider using Scrapy that first solves a CAPTCHA in a redirected address before accessing the main website I intend to scrape. It says that I have an HTTP error causing an infinite loop but I can't find which part of the script is causing this.

In the middleware:

```
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect import RedirectMiddleware

class ProtectRedirectMiddleware(RedirectMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        super().__init__(settings)
        self.source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://sampleurlname.com/')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    def _redirect(self, redirected, request, spider, reason):
        # act normally if this isn't a CAPTCHA redirect
        if not self.is_protected(redirected.url):
            return super()._redirect(redirected, request, spider, reason)

        # if this is a CAPTCHA redirect
        logger.debug(f'The protect URL is triggered for {request.url}')
        request.cookies = self.bypass_protection(redirected.url)
        request.dont_filter = True 
        return request

    def is_protected(self, url):
        return 'sampleurlname.com/protect' in url

    def bypass_protection(self, url=None):
        # only navigate if any explicit url is provided
        if url:
            url = url or self.source.geturl(url)

        img = soup.find_all('img')[0]
        imgurl = img['src']
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgurl, "captcha.png")
        return self.solve_captcha(imgurl)

        # wait for the redirect and try again
        self.wait_for_redirect()
        return self.bypass_protection()

    def wait_for_redirect(self, url = None, wait = 0.1, timeout=10):
        url = self.url
        for i in range(int(timeout//wait)):
            time.sleep(wait)
            if self.response.url() != url:
                return self.response.url()
        logger.error(f'Maybe {self.response.url()} isn\'t a redirect URL')
        raise Exception('Timed out')

    def solve_captcha(self, img, width=150, height=50):
        # open image
        self.img = 'captcha.png'
        img = Image.open("captcha.png")

        # image manipulation - simplified
        # input the captcha text - simplified
        # click the submit button - simplified
        # save the URL 
        url = self.response.url()

        # try again if wrong
        if self.is_protected(self.wait_for_redirect(url)):
            return self.bypass_protection()

        # return the cookies as a dict
        cookies = {}
        for cookie_string in self.response.css.cookies():
            if 'domain=sampleurlname.com' in cookie_string:
                key, value = cookie_string.split(';')[0].split('=')
                cookies[key] = value
        return cookies
```

Then, this is the error I get when I run the scrapy crawl of my spider:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-08-06 16:34:33 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-08-06 16:34:33 [twisted] CRITICAL:

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 36, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/redirect.py", line 26, in from_crawler
    return cls(crawler.settings)

    File "/username/...../scraper/myscraper/myscraper/middlewares.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://sampleurlname.com/')

    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 564, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)

    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
```

It basically repeats the bottom part of these over and over: open, http_response, error, _call_chain, and http_error_302, until these show at the end:

```
    File "/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 746, in http_error_302
    self.inf_msg + msg, headers, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 307: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Temporary Redirect
```

In setting.py is:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': None,
'myscrape.middlewares.ProtectRedirectMiddleware': 600}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with scrapy itself. You are using blocking requests in your middleware initiation. 
This request seems to be stuck in a redirect loop. This usually happens when websites do not act appropriately and require cookies to allow you through:

1. First you connect and get a redirect response 30x and some setCokies headers
2. You redirect again but not with `Cookies` headers and the page lets you through

Python urllib doesn't handle cookies, so try this:

```
import urllib
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar

def __init__(self):
    try:
        req=urllib.request.Request(url)
        cj = CookieJar()
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        response = opener.open(req)
        source = response.read().decode('utf8', errors='ignore')
        response.close()
    except urllib.request.HTTPError as e:
        logging.error(f"couldn't initiate middleware: {e}")
        return
    # you should use scrapy selectors instead of beautiful soup here
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    selector = Selector(text=source)
```

Alternatively you should use `requests` package that handles cookies by itself.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Unfortunately this won't work either and still gives me the same 307 error with infinite loop